# How to translate a BDS excel-formula to XBBG API for Python

Tags: python, excel, api, bloomberg

I have the following Bloomberg BDS excel-formula:
(";" is substituted with "," due to different settings in excel)

```
=@BSD(”TSLA US Equity”;”CHAIN_TICKERS”;”CHAIN_EXP_DT_OVRD=20210917”;”CHAIN_PUT_CALL_TYPE_OVRD=CALL”;”CHAIN_POINTS_OVRD=1000”)
```

In this instance, from this I get a list of all call option tickers for tickers, with expiration on 17/09/2021 (DDMMYYYY) for TSLA.

When trying to translate it to the XBBG API for Bloomberg, I have done the following (based on earlier helpful advice from SO'er):

```
import xbbg as blp
df = blp.bds(['TSLA US Equity'],
['CHAIN_TICKERS'],
CHAIN_EXP_DT_OVRD='CHAIN_EXP_DT_OVRD=20210917',
CHAIN_PUT_CALL_TYPE_OVRD='CHAIN_PUT_CALL_TYPE_OVRD=CALL',
CHAIN_POINTS_OVRD='CHAIN_POINTS_OVRD=1000')
```

But I only get a single data point returned, not the entire list.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `,CHAIN_EXP_DT_OVRD='20210917',`  Etc perhaps? You are repeating the override label otherwise.

Comment: It worked, thank you once again! I think it is curious, because if you use the blp.bdp, in the options you have to write ie. IVOL_DELTA_LEVEL='IVOL_DELTA_LEVEL=25', but maybe I just misunderstand the difference between options in bdp and overrides in bds. Anyway, thank you so much.

Comment: BDP (current) and BDH (historical) do not necessarily use the same override values. For BDP it is `IVOL_DELTA_LEVEL=25` (as the BDP override value is a number) but for BDH it is `IVOL_DELTA_LEVEL='DELTA_LVL_25'` (as the BDH override value is one of a set of string-based options). Admittedly this is confusing but comes about because BDP and BDH use different mechanisms on the server side.

Comment: When the API gets an override value it doesn't understand, it just shrugs and ignores it. So when you used `IVOL_DELTA_LEVEL='IVOL_DELTA_LEVEL=25'`, the API didn't know what you meant, and ignored the override, defaulting to `IVOL_DELTA_LEVEL=50` (ie ATM strike). You might have thought it was working because you got data back without error, but most likely that data was for the wrong delta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying the parameters incorrectly. The function does not understand the CHAIN_POINTS_OVRD value, so is falling back to the default of 1, which is why the returned dataframe only has one value.

With `xbbg` you can usually supply Python types, with the override name becoming the parameter name (no quotes) in the `bds` call. So in this case the date override can be a `datetime` value, and the chain points override can be a number.

```
from xbbg import blp
from datetime import datetime

df = blp.bds('TSLA US Equity',
             'CHAIN_TICKERS',
             CHAIN_EXP_DT_OVRD=datetime(2021,9,17),
             CHAIN_PUT_CALL_TYPE_OVRD='CALL',
             CHAIN_POINTS_OVRD=1000)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                ticker
TSLA US Equity     TSLA US 09/17/21 C1
TSLA US Equity     TSLA US 09/17/21 C2
TSLA US Equity     TSLA US 09/17/21 C3
TSLA US Equity     TSLA US 09/17/21 C4
TSLA US Equity     TSLA US 09/17/21 C5
...                                ...
TSLA US Equity  TSLA US 09/17/21 C1600
TSLA US Equity  TSLA US 09/17/21 C1625
TSLA US Equity  TSLA US 09/17/21 C1650
TSLA US Equity  TSLA US 09/17/21 C1675
TSLA US Equity  TSLA US 09/17/21 C1700

[334 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you once agian! I have a follow-up question regarding looping through the df, using the tickers from the BDS as input for a BDP, but my loop is so far really slow. Should I just ask here or should I ask a new question on how to most efficiently loop through a df?

Comment: @Jørgen Feel free to ‘tick’ and accept my answer: this will show other users that the solution worked. As for looping, it is not the dataframe which is slowing you down, but making 300+ separate bdp calls each of which require a round-trip to the Bloomberg servers.

Comment: Thank you once again DS_London, explain to me where to tick, you have been very helpful and of course should be recognised for this.