# Bloomberg xbbg and download historical option data

Tags: api, bloomberg

When I tried to download historical option price using xbbg there is a problem:

in the excel, I use =BDS("SPY US Equity", "opt_chain","single_date_override",text(20191010,"YYYYMMDD") ), I can get the option chain for SPY on 20191010, but in the xbbg (in the juypter notebook), it says "bds() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given".

does any one know how can I solve this?

Also, did someone has written a python script before, which can download historical option data for any ticker, including daily OHLCV and open interest, for both bid and ask?

Very appreciated.

Best

Comment: Can you show the  command that doesn't work?

Comment: try: `=BDS("SPY US Equity", "opt_chain", single_date_override="20191010")`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68999997/15877695) should work.